# Why does `pip3 install lxml` on public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11 install a source distribution rather than a (manylinux) wheel?

Tags: python, linux, pip, python-poetry, python-wheel

I'm curious to understand why `pip3` @ `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11` (Python v3.11.4) downloads and install the source distribution of `lxml` instead of downloading the seemingly compatible manylinux wheel `lxml-4.9.3-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_28_aarch64.whl`?

https://pypi.org/project/lxml/#files

The above wheel is downloaded e.g. by `pip3` @ `amazonlinux` (Python v3.11.2):

[image]

**Example**:

```
$ docker run -ti --rm --user 0 --platform linux/arm64 --entrypoint bash public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11
$ pip3 install lxml
```

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the terminal output and format it as code, like the commands that you showed. We don't need to see the coloured text in order to understand the problem. Anyway, you first: why do you think it should use the wheel instead?

Comment: Use `pip debug --verbose` to see which tags are compatible, then compare that to the list of available wheels.

Answer (score 4):

```bash
bash-4.2# ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.26
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

The docker image uses glibc 2.26, the manylinux wheel is built for glibc 2.28+ ([that's what the `2_28` in the filename stands for](https://peps.python.org/pep-0600/#core-definition)).

Comment: Thank you! Can you elaborate on how you identified this? Which files inside the wheel did you look into? Does `pip` output something like "glibc 2.28 is not available, so reverting to source distribution"?